# Lock item in Cache ASP.NET MVC due to concurrency issues

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching

I am using the following methods to do some simple caching. The problem is, I need to cache a session token for some API access, which is good for 24 hours.

The issue with that is, if my api call bounces because the token expired I want to use the below refresh method. But, I would imagine there will be a concurrency issue, if a client request is deleting/refreshing the token while the next client has already checked the existence of the token and will start to also refresh delete the token they may have a problem. How can I lock access to this token efficiently while it is refreshes?

```
 public class CacheUtils : ICacheService
    {
        public T Get<T>(string cacheKey, int hoursUntilExpire, Func<T> getItemCallback) where T : class
        {
            var item = HttpRuntime.Cache.Get(cacheKey) as T;
            if (item != null) return item;
            item = getItemCallback();
            HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(cacheKey, item, null, DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(hoursUntilExpire), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
            return item;
        }

        public void Refresh(string key)
        {
            HttpRuntime.Cache.Remove(key);
            //Somehow refresh here with lock
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said you can introduce a lock:

```
public class CacheUtils : ICacheService
{
    private readonly object _lock = new object();
    public T Get<T>(string cacheKey, int hoursUntilExpire, Func<T> getItemCallback) where T : class
    {
        T item;
        lock (_lock) 
        {
           item = HttpRuntime.Cache.Get(cacheKey) as T;
        }

        if (item != null) return item;
        item = getItemCallback();

        lock (_lock)
        {
             HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(cacheKey, item, null, DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(hoursUntilExpire), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
        }
        return item;
    }

    public void Refresh(string key)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            HttpRuntime.Cache.Remove(key);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! But is it necessary to have lock on this line: item = HttpRuntime.Cache.Get(cacheKey) as T?

Comment: @Ilya.N. it will insure that while you're getting the item it's not removed by another user. I'm not sure about `Insert` though